# C++ daemon silence mode

Tags: c++, daemon, cout, silent

I am writing daemon under unix system and using `std::cout` at the code to debug at `no silent` mode. When I start the process at `daemon/silence mode`, I `close(STDIN_FILENO)`, `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO` to save resources on printing to `std::cout`. Seems when closed, its writes to `/dev/null`, isn't it? Is it correct and best way to avoid overhead of resources at silence mode? Or maybe I need to use global `silent flag` and check it every time before any call to `std::cout`? Or other solutions? thanks, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is implemented by writing to `STDOUT_FILENO`.  Closing the latter breaks the former.

Comment: and it is the best way to make daemon silence?

Comment: @abrahab:  The *best way* is to remove output statements from the daemon.  The usual method is to redirect stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.  Maybe a command line switch or environment variable could make the daemon choose a level of verbosity by selectively writing some things and not others.